# mPDF not not using constructor parameters

Tags: php, drupal, printing, mpdf

I am trying to use mPDF in a custom Drupal site to create PDF output of a certain page created in a custom module. I have my page working fine and I am able to create the html page I would like to convert to pdf. I can display this html file and it looks fine. The html page has a large styles section in the head section.

I am currently developing on an XAMPP environment.

In my code I have the following constructor

```
include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\drupal\\sites\\all\\modules\\print\\lib\\mpdf.php');

$mpdf = new mPDF('c','A4-L');
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents('C:\\temp\\test.html'));
$mpdf->Output('c:\\temp\\test.pdf','F');
```

I am trying to create a blank A4 page with Landscape orientation. I have done a lot of hunting online and this seems fine.

When I run this I get the test.pdf file created.

When I look at the pdf file I see a page rendered in portrait. The page contains everything it should but in portrait instead of landscape.

Looking at the mPDF reference documentation it appears to me that I am using the correct parameters. No matter what I try it seems I am stuck with the default parameters. I have even tried commenting out the include and it makes no difference.

Can anyone suggest where I can look to get the constructor parameters working?

Comment: try this  `$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L');` 
size/format 
`$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', array(190,236));` Source http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=306

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L',0,0,0,0,11);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents('C:\\temp\\test.html'));
$mpdf->Output('c:\\temp\\test.pdf','F');
```

Comment: The pdf file has increased from 4K to 18K with that modification but the page is still portrait orientation